# Elements break line when sum of widths equal 100%

Tags: css

I'm trying put a `input` and a `button` display inline, where `input` need fill 70% of row, and `button` 30%

So, I set css 70% and 30% to elements, but elements will break line

How to can I fix this problem?

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

input {
  width: 70%;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this:

```
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

It's because the input/button has padding and border added by the browser so the total ends up > 100%.

What the code above does is tell all elements to include padding and border into the width value.

You will also be suffering from a white-spacing issue. Basically because your elements are on a separate line, it adds white space in-between. To combat this you can either put them on the same line with no space or comment the area in-between, like so:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
}
input {
  width: 70%;
  border: 3px solid;
}
button {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text"><!--
  --><button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Setting the `div` element to have `font-size: 0px;` would also work to remove the white-space, as long as you're not affecting the relative font-size of any child elements by doing so.

Comment: I increment this in CSS, but is not working

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kacidaxoga/edit?css,output

Comment: Not working from here too.

Comment: @Lai32290 There was a second part causing it to not work. Added the extra information to the answer

Comment: why <!-- --> is necessary for fix this problem?

Comment: @Lai32290 As I said in the answer, they are on a separate line so it adds white-space in-between the elements. The other alternative is to put them on the same line.

Comment: The comment-white-space stuff just blew my head off D:

Answer (score -1):

The button has a border by default so 30 plus 70 is actually a little above 100% try this:

```
input {
  float: left;  
  width: 69%;
}
button {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```